# WebClient DownloadString gives 400 Bad Request error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webclient, html-agility-pack

I am trying to download html of a web page (https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/#/home) as string to parse further using HtmlAgilityPack
But it throw 400 bad Request , Below is the code that I tried.

Code Approach 1 using WebClient

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {
        #region Html Download
        string baseURL = "https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/#/home";
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        string html = client.DownloadString(baseURL);
        #endregion
      }
```

Code Approach 2 using HtmlAgilityPack(version 1.11.34)

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/#/home");
```

Also tried to set below attribute

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
   client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
   client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
   client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
   client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
   html = client.DownloadString("https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/#/home");
 }
```

But still get the same error,

Is something is missing here or need to escape # symbol in URL ?

Comment: I've tried it with `HttpClient` and it worked. Could you please test it with `HttpClient.GetAsync()`?

Comment: Don't use HtmlAgilityPack. Use AngleSharp.

Comment: @IanKemp any specific reason to suggest AngleSharp over HtmlAgilityPack ?

Comment: Because it's better?

Comment: @PhilippApe tried using "HttpClient.GetAsync()" but did not get the complete html, Look like that web page developed in angular js and your suggested method only scrap html without any body content in it.